# dotnet 6 minimal API circular serialization

Tags: c#, .net-core, minimal-apis

I am new to dotnet, trying out dotnet 6 minimal API. I have two models:

```
namespace Linker.Models
{
    class Link : BaseEntity
    {
        [MaxLength(2048)]
        public string Url { get; set;} = default!;
        [MaxLength(65536)]
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public User Owner { get; set; } = default!;
        [Required]
        public Space Space { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```

And:

```
namespace Linker.Models
{
    class Space : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Code { get; set; } = default!;
        public User Owner { get; set; } = default!;
        public List<Link> Links { get; set; } = new List<Link>();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to serialize `Space` model I get error `System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64.` (make sense because `Path: $.Links.Space.Links.Space.Links.Space.Links.Space.Links.Space.Links...`). Is it posible to prevent dotnet from serializing object this deep? I don't need for dotnet to even try to serialize such a deep relations

Comment: Add a new model without link.

Comment: Why would I need do that? I have normal models with simple one to may relation, how would third model help in this case? How can I have model relation without relation?

Comment: I would suggest that you use two separate models. One in business logic and one to be exposed by the API. Thus, you can precisely define the data expected/returned by the API.

Comment: The answer is "it depends". Because you can see the circular references yourself. You need to specify what should happen if a circular reference is encountered: that's business logic. So: what's the requirement?

Comment: @JHBonarius requirement is: when serializing space entity I need to have related `Link` entities, when  serializing `Link` entity no need to have `Space` entity. BUT, when deserializing `Link` entity (creating new one), I need to have access to `Space` entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `ReferenceHandler.Preserve` in the `JsonSerializerOptions`. These docs
[How to preserve references and handle or ignore circular references in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0) discuss further.

For manual serialization/deserialization pass the options to the `JsonSerializer`:

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
{
    ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve
};
string serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, options);
```

Or to configure globally in minimal API:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Set the JSON serializer options
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
});
```

You could instead [ignore the circular references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0#ignore-circular-references) rather than handling them by using `ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles`. The serializer will set the circular references to `null`, so there's potential for data loss using this method.

Comment: Thank You. First solution is working, but global configuration is getting ignored

Comment: The example for configuring it globally did not work for me.  I had to do it as shown on the Microsoft page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization

Answer (score 3):

The reason the global configuration is getting ignored is because the wrong JsonOptions is being used. The following should work:

builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options =>

... rest of code

My default for JsonOptions is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions, which was not the correct JsonOptions object to change and so globally did not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [JsonIgnore] before the Space declaration as below:

```
namespace Linker.Models
{
    class Link : BaseEntity
    {
        [MaxLength(2048)]
        public string Url { get; set;} = default!;
        [MaxLength(65536)]
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public User Owner { get; set; } = default!;
        [JsonIgnore]
        [Required]
        public Space Space { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```